# Stopping N number of nodes of a Cassandra cluster running on a single machine using bash script

Tags: cassandra

I have set up a Multi-Node cassandra (3.11) cluster (with N nodes) in a **single Ubuntu machine**. I have written a bash script which

- Creates N copies of **conf** folder
- Configures the cassandra **yaml** file according to the need of N nodes (Such as separating the data and log directories)
- Creates N copies of cassandra script inside the bin folder

It works correctly so far. But I am a little stuck after that.

**I want to stop all the nodes effectively at the end of the script**. Any help will be really appreciated at this point.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I figured it out:

```
kill $(ps auwx | grep '[c]assandra' | awk '{print $2}')
```